# Snap SVG path animation from the top not left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, snap.svg

I have some SVG's that I would like to animate on hover, I am 90% there now, however, the actual animation doesn't look too great, I would like it to appear as sliding up almost but at the moment it looks as though its coming in and out from the left.

I have created a Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SeriousJelly/qhaqrju5/1

```
    $(function() {

    //Grab an array of all the main SVG Elements
    var containers = $(".category .item a");

    //Define some vars that we will use later
    var speed = 1000;
    var animation = mina.backout;

    //Loop through all of these containers and insert the SVG's
    containers.each(function( index ) {

        //Get each of our SVG tags
        var s = Snap(".animated-overlay.svg-" + index);

        //Define our Paths
        var defaultBluePath = "M89.73,22.34c0,0-11.02-2.41-18.56-2.41c-17.36,0-31.17,6.23-53.67,6.23c-9.94,0-17.48-1.19-17.48-1.19V0h89.72V22.34z";
        var defaultWhitePath = "M17.5,26.17c-9.94,0-17.48-1.19-17.48-1.19v3.05c0,0,7.55,0.67,17.48,0.67c19.45,0,36.41-7.51,53.77-7.51c10.51,0,18.47,2.01,18.47,2.01v-0.86c0,0-11.02-2.41-18.56-2.41C53.81,19.94,40,26.17,17.5,26.17z";

        //Define our Hover Paths
        var hoverBluePath = "M0.02,0 h89.72 v13.25 h-89.72z";
        var hoverWhitePath = "M0,13.2 h89.75 v0.7 h-89.75z";

        //Load up the default paths in the SVG
        var bluePath = s.path(defaultBluePath);
        var whitePath = s.path(defaultWhitePath);

        //Define our Default Path Atributes
        bluePath.attr({ fill: "#16325C" });
        whitePath.attr({ fill: "#FFFFFF" });

        //Let's group our paths, it doesn't seem like you can animate the whole group though :(
        var paths = s.group(bluePath, whitePath);

        //Animate on Mouse Enter
        $(containers[index]).mouseenter(function() {
            bluePath.animate({ path: hoverBluePath }, speed, animation);
            whitePath.animate({ path: hoverWhitePath }, speed, animation);
        });

        //Animate on Mouse Leave, return the paths to the default
        $(containers[index]).mouseleave(function() {
            bluePath.animate({ path: defaultBluePath }, speed, animation);
            whitePath.animate({ path: defaultWhitePath }, speed, animation);  
        });



    });

});
```

It would be great, if someone could take a look and help tidy up the animation or explain how it works?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Simplify it further. Break it down into one path, and get it to move like you want it to first. Its quite hard to figure, as not sure what you actually want it do look like. If you want it to slide up, why not just put a transform on it to move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Used a better `defaultWhitePath`, now it transition smoothly.

```
        //Define our Paths
        var defaultBluePath = "M0,0 L0,25 C42,36 50,11 90,23 L90,0";
        var defaultWhitePath = "M0,25 C42,36 50,11 90,23 L90,25 C50,11 42,46 0,30Z";

        //Define our Hover Paths
        var hoverBluePath = "M0.02,0 L0,13 L90,13 L90,0 Z";
        var hoverWhitePath = "M0,13 L90,13";
```

Above changes tested on FF.

Comment: That is perfect! Exactly what I was trying to achieve! Works great in Chrome too! Thanks a lot, saved me a lot of headache with this one.